# Can t autowired CRUD repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, autowired

I have interface with crud repository:

```
public interface LekarDao extends  CrudRepository<Lekarfizo, Long> {

     Lekarfizo findByBrojLicence(String brojLicence);
  }
```

And i have service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class LekarDaoImpl {

@Autowired
private LekarDao lekarDao;


 public Lekarfizo nadjipoIdu(String jmbg){

   return lekarDao.findByBrojLicence(jmbg);
 }
```

My xml:

```
 <context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dao" />
 <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
   <jpa:repositories base-package="com.dao"/>
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
 <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="ProjekatOrdPU" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

I have error:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.dao.LekarDao com.dao.LekarDaoImpl.lekarDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lekarDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor

I realy don t know what i am doing wrong.
I use Spring 4.0.1,spring-data-jpa 1.10.1 ,spring-data-commons 1.10.0.

Comment: If you are using Maven post your POM.

Comment: The Javadoc for QueryByExampleExecutor notes that this Interface exists in spring-data-commons from **v1.12**: see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/index.html?org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor.html. You appear to have a library conflict. Are you using any dependency manager?

Comment: i don t use maven i just download jar ,spring-commons-data 1.10.0 and spring data jpa 1.10.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javadoc for QueryByExampleExecutor notes that this Interface was added to spring-data-commons from v1.12 so it would appear that spring-data-jpa 1.10 has a dependency on spring-data-commons 1.12 and not 1.10 as you currently have.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/query/QueryByExampleExecutor.html

> public interface QueryByExampleExecutor Interface to allow
>   execution of Query by Example Example instances. **Since:
>   1.12**

Altough you are not using Maven, you can confirm the required versions of any dependencies by looking inside the spring-data-jpa 1.10 JAR file. In the file META-INF/maven/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/pom.xml.

This has the following property set:

```
<springdata.commons>1.12.1.RELEASE</springdata.commons>
```

Managing dependencies manually will become extremely difficult on anything other than the simplest projects. You should look at using a build tool like Maven or Gradle.